# Use sage to compute ring quotient

Tags: sage

Let =ℚ(√2) and =() where ^2++1=0 is one of the cubic roots of unity. Let a be a primitive element of L, O_K the ring of algebraic integers. How do I then compute quotients like O_K/Z[a]? I tried:

```
K.<sqrt2> = NumberField(x^2-2)
L.<w> = K.extension(x^2+x+1)
a = L.primitive_element()
print L.ring_of_integers().quotient(ZZ[a])
```

However I always get errors like: "unable to convert Relative Order in Number Field in w0 with defining polynomial x^2 + (2*sqrt2 + 1)*x + sqrt2 + 3 over its base field to Number Field in w with defining polynomial x^2 + x + 1 over its base field".

What is the correct syntax here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have noted, the problem is that we have `w` and `w0` and they don't seem to agree.  At [this documentation link](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/number_fields/sage/rings/number_field/number_field.html#sage.rings.number_field.number_field.NumberField_absolute.order), we have an interesting example.

```
sage: K.<a> = NumberField(x^3 - 2)
sage: ZZ[a]
Order in Number Field in a0 with defining polynomial x^3 - 2 with a0 = a
```

This leads me to try

```
sage: K.<a> = NumberField(x^3 - 2)
sage: Za = ZZ[a]
sage: OK = K.maximal_order()
sage: Za.is_suborder(OK)
False
sage: OK.is_suborder(Za)
False
sage: OK
Maximal Order in Number Field in a with defining polynomial x^3 - 2
sage: Za
Order in Number Field in a0 with defining polynomial x^3 - 2 with a0 = a
sage: OK.number_field()
Number Field in a with defining polynomial x^3 - 2
sage: Za.number_field()
Number Field in a0 with defining polynomial x^3 - 2 with a0 = a
sage: OK.number_field() == Za.number_field()
False
```

And as we can see, even though `a0=a` there is apparently no way to directly compare even the underlying number fields.  I'm not at all an expert in this part of the code, but I think it deserves a ticket for clarification at the least.  I've opened [Trac 28706](https://trac.sagemath.org/ticket/28706).

---

In the meantime, if you can find a way to get the order you want using the usual syntax for orders, I'd do that.  For the example I made from the documentation, I think `Za` and `OK` are the same, but for yours I tried this.

```
sage: Za.gens()
(1, w0, (-2*sqrt2 - 1)*w0 - sqrt2 - 3, (3*sqrt2 + 6)*w0 + 7*sqrt2 + 7)
sage: O1 = L.order([1,w,(-2*sqrt2 - 1)*w - sqrt2 - 3, (3*sqrt2 + 6)*w + 7*sqrt2 + 7])
sage: O1.is_suborder(OK)
True
```

which is certainly an improvement.  Alas,

```
sage: OK.quotient(O1)
TypeError: unable to convert Maximal Relative Order in Number Field in w with defining polynomial x^2 + x + 1 over its base field to Number Field in w with defining polynomial x^2 + x + 1 over its base field
```

so now I am out of my depth.  Are such quotients allowed per se?  You may have to create an [ideal](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/number_fields/sage/rings/number_field/number_field_ideal.html) instead to perform this action.  Good luck!